# HTML image & other components resize according to width of page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am developing HTML5 css3 & js based game.
So i want everything should be resizable such as text, font, images according to width & height of screen.
For text & font i found that instead of putting value in px i will make it em so that it will be relatively scale accourding to body font size.
Now i want to know how can i do this for images & other stuff.

```
<div id="titlediv" style="text-align: center; position: relative; height: 20%;
    width: 90%; margin: 0px auto; padding: 40px 0px 40px 5px; margin-top: 0%;">
        <p style="font-family: 'Arial'; font-size: 400%;">
            Quiz Game
        </p>
        <br />
        <p style="font-family: 'Arial Rounded MT Bold'; font-size: 150%;">
            The definitive place for games
        </p>
</div>
```

So this is just for game title rest of code is same like this

Comment: Well those are just text... you should be using ems for their resizing and then text-align center should keep them in place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your css use % values for width and height instead of px values.

```
img.thumbnail {
  width: 25%
  height: 25%;
  /* Whatever else */
}
```

Comment: Thanks for quick responce but i have lots of images so their postion also i want to set according to the scale.
I want to say i have 16 images tile(4*4) so it should look consistent

Comment: @JMoh Edit your question & push your code for better understanding is what you want

Comment: If you're wanting them to resize that's going to be percentages. The position is going to be a seperate issue. Like sandeep said post your code and fix the question.

Answer (score 0):

set all the dimensions of divs.images in % or em. For e.g

```
<div class="row">
  <img src ="url" />
  <img src ="url" />
  <img src ="url" />
  <img src ="url" />
</div>
```

css :

```
.row{width:100%}
.row img{width:20%; display:inline; margin:5% 2.5%}
```

Make sure that the sum total width of the images inside row div is always 100% including padding and margin or else it will distort the layout.

Answer (score 0):

> also use the position and float with width and height img.thumbnail { 
>   width: x%   height: y%;   position:relative;
>        /* Whatever else */ }